# Get Email Address of every Person in Array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, email, meteor

I am trying to send an email to every person in an array. So I need the email adress from every person. I have a collection with the name of the person and the email adress the collection is named Benutzer/ benutzer.

Here is my code on the client:

```
Template.NeuesEvent.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('events');
    this.subscribe('friends');
    this.subscribe('benutzer');
});

Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var Name = event.target.name.value;
        var Beschreibung = event.target.beschreibung.value;
        var Datum = event.target.Datum.value;
        var Autor = Meteor.userId();
        var eingeladene = []; <-- this is the array
             $.each($('.FreundeCheckbox:checked'), function(){            
                eingeladene.push($(this).val());
            });

       var email = Meteor.Benutzer.findOne({"email": eingeladene});<<------

       <<---- here i want to grab the email adress 


        if (Name == "")
        {
            confirm("Das Event braucht einen Namen ;)")
        }
        else {

        Meteor.call('addEvent', Name, Beschreibung, Datum, eingeladene, Autor, email) <<--
<<------and paste the information here

        event.target.name.value = "";
        event.target.beschreibung.value = "";
        FlowRouter.go('/meineEvents');

        return false;
    }
    }
});
```

this is my method.js but the email function is not inside it now but I already know how to do that

```
Meteor.methods({
    addEvent(Name, Beschreibung, Datum, eingeladene, Autor, email) {
         Events.insert({
            Name: Name,
            Beschreibung: Beschreibung,
            erstelltAm: new Date(),
            Datum: Datum,
            Eingeladen: eingeladene,
            Autor: Autor
        });

SSR.compileTemplate('InviteEmail', Assets.getText('Invite-Email.html'));
        var emailData = {
            Name: Name,
            Beschreibung: Beschreibung,
            erstelltAm: new Date(),
            Datum: Datum,
            Eingeladen: eingeladene,
            Autor: Autor
        };

    Email.send({
        to: email, <<<-----everytime a new one 
        from: "example@email.com",
        subject: "Einladung",
        html: SSR.render('InviteEmail', emailData),
      });
        }
    });
```

So now you know what i try to do you can help me now with two problems first getting the email adress and second how to loop over the email.send function with every email adress again

Comment: I recommend you only use `_id`s on the client. Pass an array of user `_id`s to Meteor.call() and let the server do the finding of users and the extraction of their email addresses. This will avoid exposing other user email addresses out to the client (more secure) and will reduce the latency of the operation. Don't forget to invoke `this.unblock()` in your method to avoid the method blocking other requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not write comments into the code without really commenting it:

**Wrong:**

`var eingeladene = []; <-- this is the array`

**Better:**

```
var eingeladene = []; // <-- this is the array
```

Remember, your eingeladene is an array, this returns nothing:

```
var email = Meteor.Benutzer.findOne({"email": eingeladene});
```

the correct way to do this is:

```
var email = Meteor.Benutzer.findOne({"email": {$in: eingeladene}});
```

Anyway, what I would do, I'd send array of emails to the method and do things there. Something like this.

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var Name = event.target.name.value;
        var Beschreibung = event.target.beschreibung.value;
        var Datum = event.target.Datum.value;
        var Autor = Meteor.userId();
        var eingeladene = []; 
         $.each($('.FreundeCheckbox:checked'), function(){            
            eingeladene.push($(this).val());
        });

        // we dont't need email yet

        if (Name == "")
        {
            confirm("Das Event braucht einen Namen ;)")
        }
        else {

        // removed Autor and email here, since we don't need it
        Meteor.call('addEvent', Name, Beschreibung, Datum, eingeladene);

        event.target.name.value = "";
        event.target.beschreibung.value = "";
        FlowRouter.go('/meineEvents');

        return false;
    }
    }
}); 

Meteor.methods({
    'addEvent': function(Name, Beschreibung, Datum, eingeladene) {
        this.unblock();
        var Autor = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);

         Events.insert({
            Name: Name,
            Beschreibung: Beschreibung,
            erstelltAm: new Date(),
            Datum: Datum,
            Eingeladen: eingeladene,
            Autor: Autor
        });

        SSR.compileTemplate('InviteEmail', Assets.getText('Invite-Email.html'));
        var emailData = {
            Name: Name,
            Beschreibung: Beschreibung,
            erstelltAm: new Date(),
            Datum: Datum,
            Eingeladen: eingeladene,
            Autor: Autor
        };

        // do you really need the fetch emails from the collection?

        for (var i in eingeladene) {
            var email = Meteor.Benutzer.findOne({"email": eingeladene[i]});
            if (!email) {
                continue;
            }


            Email.send({
                to: email, <<<-----everytime a new one 
                from: "example@email.com",
                subject: "Einladung",
                html: SSR.render('InviteEmail', emailData),
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you it helped very much ;) but when i test it out to find the email adress i get the error: Can not read property "findOne" of undefined  and the internet did not told me the solution ;(    And what do you mean with really fetch the emails im not fetching anything or am i wrong?

Comment: sorry forgot it in the first comment @iiro

Comment: @Michael hard to say. Perhas you should import some file, where is your Meteor.Benutzer. defined? I usually put collection definitions into /lib directory so client and server see them. 

Benutzer = new Meteor.Collection('benutzer');

later...

Benutzer.findOne(...)

Comment: yes it is already in the lib folder and now i found the key too thank you for your help ;) @iiro

Comment: @Michael ok great! Then you should accept the answer, i can edit for corrections. What you did that you got it to work?

Comment: great idea this is what i have done: var email =  Benutzer.findOne({"Vorname": eingeladene[i]}, {fields: {email: 1} }); @iiro